# Voltage in an Inductor

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, inductance

When an inductor is connected with a voltage source we get equal and opposite voltage on inductor against the source voltage. That equal and opposite voltage gradually decreases with time which allows the current(caused by the source voltage) to rise gradually.

My question is what makes the equal and opposite voltage in an inductor to fall gradually ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor

Comment: Ummm... What you say happens does not happen --- unless there is something in the circuit other than the inductor and the voltage source. If there is only a voltage source and an inductor, the voltage stays constant and the current increates linearly with time,

Comment: @mikestone in a pure inductor there will be back emf. In a perfect inductor with a constant applied voltage, the back emf equals that applied voltage so, how can current flow? the back emf has to decrease then so that the current may rise.

Comment: If I push on something, it pushes back on me with an equal and opposite force (Newton's third law) --- yet the object still moves!   This is because  in  $F=ma$ it's the force *I* apply to the object that it is "$F$." Same here.  $LdI/dt=V$ where $V$ is voltage applied by the *battery*.  The applied $V$ does not inlcude the back EMF.

Comment: @mikestone both battery voltage and back emf are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction and they are pushing same electrons. isnt it like the case where you and me pushing an object with equal and opposite force ?

Comment: No. it is not. The same argument  applies to a resistor as applies to an inductor. The voltage drops across the resistor is $V=IR$, just as the voltage drop across an inductor is $V=L dI/dt$. In a Kirchhoff circuit the potential goes up as you pass through the battery and drops as you pass through the inductor or resistor. Total change in potential round the circuit is zero.